# Proving the bound $\left ( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n \leqslant 3^x$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^+}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, closed-form

I'm trying to directly prove the above bound. I have tried expanding it

$$\left ( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n = \sum_{k\geqslant 0} \binom{n}{k}\left ( \frac{x}{n}\right)^k$$

$$= \sum_{k=0\dots n }x^k\cdot \frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n^k}\cdot \frac{1}{k!}$$

$$\leqslant \sum_{k=0\dots n} \frac{x^k}{k!} \leqslant \sum_{k=2\dots n} \frac{x^k}{k(k-1)}=\sum_{k=2\dots n} \frac{-x^k}{k}+\sum_{k=2\dots n} \frac{x^k}{k-1}$$

but can't proceed from here.

I'm not sure it's the right strategy.

Thanks

Comment: For $x > 0$, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x < 3^x$.

Comment: I'm trying to prove it as if I don't know about the various definitions of the number $e^x$

Comment: Substitution reduces it to just $(1+1/n)^n \leq 3$.

Comment: @Arthur how?...

Comment: Setting $u=n/x$ gives $(1+1/u)^{xu}\leq 3^x$. Take $x$th root on both sides, and you're there.

Comment: First, this does not hold for every real $x$ and one should probably assume that $x$ is nonnegative. Second, some of the approaches I see on this page use heavily logarithms, is this different from using exponentials (an approach you repudiated)?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Equivalence_of_characterizations_1_and_2) might interest you as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $2^{k-1}=(2)(2)\cdots (2)<(2)(3)\cdots (k)=k!$ for $k\geq 2$, 
we have 
$$\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\left({1\over n}\right)^k\leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty{1\over k!}\leq 1+1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty {1\over 2^{k-1}} =3.$$

---

**Hint 2:** If $x,n$ are positive integers, then $(1+{x\over n})\leq (1+{1\over n})^x$.
Raising this to the $n$th power, then using the bound above gives
$$\left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n\leq \left(1+{1\over n}\right)^{nx}\leq 3^x$$

Comment: Aaaaah... +1. (And with the $x$?)

Comment: @Did It's not terribly hard to modify this to handle positive integer $x$, then positive rational $x$. Taking limits will give the result for positive real $x$.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot upvote again... :-)

Answer (score 2):

If we can use the limit definition of $e$, then we have $\lim_{n\to\infty } \left(\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n/x}\right)^x = e^x < 3^x$.

Comment: But it's exactly what I want to prove - that this sequence is convergent

Comment: @AmihaiZivan, it's left to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^\frac{n}{x} = e$